# Why can't I open a .h5 file in Python?

Tags: python, tensorflow, operating-system, hdf5, h5py

I am trying to open an.h5 file, but experiencing an OS error.

```
import sys
sys.path.append('..') 
from unet3d.training import load_old_model
import tables
from train_model import config


model_file=config["model_file"] #config["model_file"] = os.path.abspath("mc_seg_model.h5")
hdf5_file=config["val_data_file"] #config['val_data_file'] = os.path.abspath("../data/val_data.h5")

model = load_old_model(model_file)
```

load_model function is as follows:

```
import math
from functools import partial
import pdb
from keras import backend as K
from keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint, CSVLogger, LearningRateScheduler, ReduceLROnPlateau, EarlyStopping
from keras.models import load_model
import tensorflow_addons as tfa

def load_old_model(model_file):
#     pdb.set_trace()
    print("Loading pre-trained model")
    custom_objects = {'dice_coefficient_loss': dice_coefficient_loss, 'dice_coefficient': dice_coefficient,
                      'weighted_dice_coefficient': weighted_dice_coefficient,
                      'weighted_dice_coefficient_loss': weighted_dice_coefficient_loss}
    try:
        #from keras_contrib.layers import InstanceNormalization
        from tfa.layers import InstanceNormalization
        custom_objects["InstanceNormalization"] = InstanceNormalization
    except ImportError:
        pass
    try:
        return load_model(model_file, custom_objects=custom_objects)
    except ValueError as error:
        if 'InstanceNormalization' in str(error):
            raise ValueError(str(error) + "\n\nPlease install keras-contrib to use InstanceNormalization:\n"
                                          "'pip install git+https://www.github.com/keras-team/keras-contrib.git'")
        else:
            raise error
```

When I try to load the model, it throws the following OS error and it is an 'Input/output error'.

```
2021-06-16 14:31:38.354199: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudart.so.10.1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "draft.py", line 35, in <module>
    model = load_old_model(model_file)
  File "../unet3d/training.py", line 50, in load_old_model
    return load_model(model_file, custom_objects=custom_objects)
  File "/share/apps/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/saving/save.py", line 182, in load_model
    return hdf5_format.load_model_from_hdf5(filepath, custom_objects, compile)
  File "/share/apps/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/saving/hdf5_format.py", line 173, in load_model_from_hdf5
    model_config = f.attrs.get('model_config')
  File "/share/apps/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/_collections_abc.py", line 660, in get
    return self[key]
  File "h5py/_objects.pyx", line 54, in h5py._objects.with_phil.wrapper
  File "h5py/_objects.pyx", line 55, in h5py._objects.with_phil.wrapper
  File "/share/apps/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/h5py/_hl/attrs.py", line 81, in __getitem__
    attr.read(arr, mtype=htype)
  File "h5py/_objects.pyx", line 54, in h5py._objects.with_phil.wrapper
  File "h5py/_objects.pyx", line 55, in h5py._objects.with_phil.wrapper
  File "h5py/h5a.pyx", line 355, in h5py.h5a.AttrID.read
  File "h5py/_proxy.pyx", line 58, in h5py._proxy.attr_rw
OSError: Unable to read attribute (file read failed: time = Wed Jun 16 14:31:42 2021
, filename = '/data/kfernando/brats20/demo_task3_mcmc/mc_seg_model.h5', file descriptor = 4, errno = 5, error message = 'Input/output error', buf = 0x56126c096440, total read size = 30352, bytes this sub-read = 30352, bytes actually read = 18446744073709551615, offset = 16384)
```

Can someone please tell me what is causing this error?

Comment: Can you open it from the command line with hdf5 tools? Like h5dump file.h5?

Comment: Is the filepath correct - /data/kfer...  Do you know which directory the program thinks it is running from?  Print os.getcwd().  Is it where you think it should be?

Comment: Debug with simple tests like `h5dump` above, or open the file with HDFView. If that works, test in python with: `import h5py` ; `h5=h5py.File(model_file,'r')` ; `h5.close()` If 1 of the first 2 tests fail, you have a problem with your file. If they work, you have an error in code.

Comment: aalways put code, data and full error message as text (not screenshot, not link) in question (not comment).

Comment: @tobias and @kcw78, when opening the file `import h5py ; h5=h5py.File(model_file,'r') ; h5.close()` this worked, I don't know why my function doesn't work. @cup file path is correct. @furas I edited the question and included the full error message as a text.

Comment: Is your `tensorflow` version up to date?  If you can open it directly with `h5py`, I wonder the `tensorflow` is using a different version of `h5py`.

Comment: The error arises when loading the model with `from keras.models import load_model; load_model(model_file)`. Why does it throw an error?

Comment: @DushiFdz Did you successfully use `h5dump` on the file?

Comment: @tobias I am not sure how to use `h5dump`. Do I have to download 'hdf5' and then on the command line type `h5dump file.h5`?

Comment: The purpose of the `h5dump` is to test if the whole file is readable.  One possibility is that the file has some how been corrupted/damaged.  `h5dump` is one the scripts that might have been installed with the underlying `HDF5` library (common in linux environments).  It's not tied to `h5py`.  But since you have opened the file with `h5py` you could explore the file with that.  But without knowing the file layout (groups, datasets etc) it's hard to identify what attribute read it's failing at.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comments about successful h5py open/close, it appears you have a valid HDF5 file. There are 2 more issues to investigate: 1) problems reading attribute data, or 2) errors in TensorFlow `load_model()` function. I can't help with TF. However here is a bit of code to recursively descend the data hierarchy and output all attributes and values. See below:

```
def get_all_attrs(name, h5_obj):
    
    if isinstance(h5_obj,h5py.Group):
        print('\n{} is a Group'.format(name))
    elif isinstance(h5_obj,h5py.Dataset):
        print('\n{} is a Dataset'.format(name))
    
    print('number of attributes:',len( h5_obj.attrs.keys() ))
    for k in h5_obj.attrs.keys():
        print('{} => {}'.format(k, h5_obj.attrs[k]))

with h5py.File(file_path, 'r') as h5r:
    print('number of root level attributes:',len( h5r.attrs.keys() ))
    for k in h5r.attrs.keys():
        print('{} => {}'.format(k, h5r.attrs[k]))        
    h5r.visititems(get_all_attrs)
```

Run this with your TF file. It might find a error reading one of the attributes. Example output from my test file looks like this:

```
number of root level attributes: 2
OS => Windows
User => Me

Base_Group is a Group
number of attributes: 2
Date => today
Time => now

Base_Group/default is a Dataset
number of attributes: 2
attr1 => 1.0
attr2 => 22.2

Group1 is a Group
number of attributes: 0

Group1/default1 is a Dataset
number of attributes: 0
```

This should help determine the source of the error. If h5py can read the attributes, you need to investigate TF `load_data()` function. If you get an error reading the attributes....well, that's your problem, but I don't know how to identify the root cause.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I tried saving a .h5 file with tf.keras and it again throws the same OS error: `RuntimeError: Problems closing file (file write failed: time = Wed Jun 16 16:43:28 2021
, filename = 'model0.h5', file descriptor = 92, errno = 5, error message = 'Input/output error', buf = 0x55babb2ea540, total write size = 3360, bytes this sub-write = 3360, bytes actually written = 18446744073709551615, offset = 277200)
/opt/gridengine/default/spool/GPU12/job_scripts/18456: line 15:  5905 Segmentation fault      (core dumped) /share/apps/anaconda3/bin/python3 cv.py > cv.txt`

Comment: I think there is more to diagnose than HDF5 issues. Your original post was about **loading** (reading) a .h5 file. This comment an error when **saving** (writing) the .h5 file. It says: `bytes actually written = 18_446_744_073_709_551_615`. Do you have a large enough drive to hold a file that size?

Comment: Yes, because I couldn't load the .h5 file, I tried to save another .h5 file and that's when the above error occurred. I am running files on a remote server (from university) and as you said I may have exceeded quota. I made a request asking to increase the quota and waiting for a reply. Hopefully, it will work then.